# Troubling making a 4 digit addition formatted in columns

Tags: tables

Hey I've been using LaTeX for about an hour, no experience in CS. Can anyone help me with this?

```
\arrayrulecolor{}
\[ \begin{array}{*4r}
   &   &   &8\\
   &   &   &8\\
   &   &   &8\\
   &   &8  &8\\
  +&8  &8  &8\\ 
  \hline
   &1  &0  &0  &0\\
   \end{array} \]
```

[image]

It comes out looking like this

Thank you anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1):

The end should be

```
\hline
   1  &0  &0  &0\\
   \end{array} \]
```

which gives 4 columns, not five, as you had.